# Entity Framework and Database Triggers

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a database which is created in a separate project and a `.edmx` model file is generated by Entity Framework and created the model classes from the existing database.

There are several things that are added to the database (other parts of the backend, front end site, api, etc). Currently the method I have is a loop that checks for new entries in the database every 5 seconds (basically just a call to the table that looks for entries newer than the most recent entry I know of), and then I use the entry to perform actions that are non database related.

I was wondering if there was a better way to get new entries as opposed to constantly querying the database for something new. I was wondering if what I'm doing is fine, or if there's a better way to get new entries, preferably able to be built upon/with EF.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to notify your app as soon as any database records are inserted or updated or deleted and do some extra processing on them then you have two choices.

You can go with `SqlDependency` or `SqlTableDependency`. Both are used to notify the application when something on database changes. There is just one constraint where you must be able to enable the Broker for SQL server using `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER` (This is important as some db doesn't support broker services i.e SQL Azure )

Here are some good links to explore both the approaches.

https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency